# Помогите смоделировать ситуацию, при который указанный код упадёт в segmentation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Суть кода в том что он построчно считывает файл/файлы в зависимости от main и выводит столько строк от файла, сколько раз вызывалась функция.
Если функция вызывается больше раз чем есть количество строк, все "лишние" вызовы должны прочитать просто последнюю строку и вернуть 0(int)

Основная проблема: main заранее неизвестен и на автоматических тестах выдаёт:

`/bin/sh: line 1: 10737 Segmentation fault: 11  ./test_gnl`
абсолютно точно проверочный main прямой и правильный
т.е. он может спровоцировать сеги только из-за моего кода

код ниже разбит на две функции, начинается с нижней части, и заканчивается верхней

```
#include "get_next_line.h"

int ft_get_next_line_2(char **sc, int fd, char **line) //вторая часть функции
{
    char    *tmp;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (sc[fd][i] != '\0' && sc[fd][i] != '\n')
        i++;
    if (sc[fd][i] == '\n')
    {
        sc[fd][i] = '\0';
        *line = ft_strsub(sc[fd], 0, i);//функция записывает в *line строку с sc[fd][0] по sc[fd][i]
        tmp = ft_strdup(sc[fd] + i + 1);//в tmp делаю дюп конца строки
        free(sc[fd]);
        sc[fd] = tmp;//сохраняю место где закончилось чтение
        if (sc[fd][0] == '\0')
            ft_strdel(&sc[fd]);//в этой функции используется free(sc[fd]) и заетм sc[fd] = NULL
    }
    else if (sc[fd][i] == '\0')
    {
        *line = ft_strdup(sc[fd]);
        ft_strdel(&sc[fd]);
    }
    return (1);
}
           /* ФУНКЦИЯ НАЧИНАЕТСЯ ЗДЕСЬ*/
int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line) 
{
    static char *sc[882];
    char        buf[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
    char        *tmp;
    int         ret;

    if (fd < 0 || line == NULL)
        return (-1);
    while ((ret = read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        if (sc[fd] == NULL)
            sc[fd] = ft_memalloc(1);
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        tmp = ft_strjoin(sc[fd], buf);// функция передаёт в tmp результат склеивания  sc[fd] и buf
        free(sc[fd]);
        sc[fd] = tmp;
        if (ft_strchr(buf, '\n'))// если в буфере находится знак новой строки, то прерываю цикл
            break ;
    }
    if (ret < 0)
        return (-1);
    if (ret == 0 && (sc[fd] == NULL || sc[fd][0] == '\0'))
        return (0);
    return (ft_get_next_line_2(sc, fd, line));//условие задачи, одна функция не должна быть больше 25 строк, поэтому пришлось разбить на вторую функцию
}
```

и сам header

```
#ifndef GET_NEXT_LINE_H
# define GET_NEXT_LINE_H
# define BUFF_SIZE 1

# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <sys/uio.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include "libft/includes/libft.h"

int get_next_line(const int fd, char **line);

#endif
```

BUFF_SIZE можем менятся от 1 до 1 000 000
у меня не получилось воспроизвести в main ошибку которую можно исправить в этом коде, и уже не могу ещё придумать как можно спровоцировать сегмент
Заранее очень благодарен, и прошу прощения за объём кода.

Comment: По полупрограмме судить о полноценной работе странно, да и на кой вам две функции??? Делается цикл, который идёт до EOF и следит за буффером, увеличивая его. И не нужно никаких статических переменных. Вы кажется усложнили всё, что можно... Реально голову сломать можно.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что `fd` всегда меньше, чем 882?!

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгий ответ, в итоге ваш комментарий помог начать копать в правильном направлении, поставил fd 255(максимум одновременно открытых файлов в Си) и поставил условие защиты если мне попытаются 256 файл подать,)